# Getting map surround as IElement in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, java, layouts

In an MXD file, I have a page layout and a map with a north arrow, and I need to move it in the page layout programmatically using ArcObjects Java SDK.

I managed to get the north arrow map surround object:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataFrame.getMapSurroundCount(); i++) {
        IMapSurround mapSurround = dataFrame.getMapSurround(i);
        if(mapSurround instanceof INorthArrow) {
            log.info("North");
            // ...
        }
        if(mapSurround instanceof IScaleBar) {
            log.info("scale bar");

        }
    }
```

Now, I need to get my north arrow as an IElement, in order to apply an Envelope as a geometry, that will cause the north arrow to be moved within the page layout.

INorthArrow cannot be cast to IElement (ever tried).

Any idea to get an IElement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the layout to `IGraphicsContainer` and call [IGraphicsContainer.FindFrame](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000005qr000000), passing the map surround as its argument. The returned frame is an `IElement` instance.

Comment: Thanks, I did it but when I get an AutomationException when I set a new geometry to the IElement: Item Not Found in this Collection. in 'DAO.Fields'

Comment: sorry, something was wrong in my Envelope creation.
It works very well now, thanks a lot!
I'll do the same for the scalebar.